# Windows 7 won't create Administrator account

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems, administrator, user-profiles, windows-error-reporting

Win7 REFUSES to login to newly created user account, logged in as admin creating 2nd admin account. The account creates fine, but always goes into a "roaming profile" login. Have deleted, and re-created with a new name, etc. Having failed every other way, enabled the "Administrator" account from the command line.

Same thing. "Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off"

**OS is refusing to create the new account profile at C:\users\blablabla ** but the why and how of this (much less how to fix it) are beyond google

I've googled every single error in eventlog... such as:

```
Windows cannot copy file \\?\C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\ to location \\?\C:\Users\TEMP\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\. This error may be caused by network problems or insufficient security rights.
```

(and many such relating to file creation of the new profile)

Have looked at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList   (the new profile, nor the administrators profile, showing up here)

Have done "cacls  c:\Users  /g everyone:F"

Have enabled all the "services" (many of which I usually turn off for simplicity sake, but this has never been a problem in the past)

Nothings working. I really dont want to have to install 7 (only 2 weeks old install) I'd like to prevent this happening again, I've installed this OS about 50 times, 5 on this h/w, never had this one before...

***Any fix other than re-install (the recovery disk didn't help either LOL) would be welcome.***

THANKS FOR RESPONSES -- Requested information:
1. Creating a local user (as default/admin/only user) on the same machine, no active directory or domain just simple home network.

2. System DOES create the new user, assigns picture, etc. 
   Try to Log INTO the new user account, system fails to create the new user account file structure, and instead logs in as "temporary". It also appears that no registry entries are made. Its a one user windows :-(  NOT a good thing. 
   Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're logging in as a local admin you need to login as computername\username, otherwise you'll be authenticating to the domain, where the username doesn't exist. Likewise if you're trying to log into a domain users account with computername\username you won't be able to authenticate because there's no local account created. The first question is: how are you creating the user account, Active Directory or Local Users and Groups?

Comment: I find your question confusing.  You say "Win7 refuses to login ..." but then "Windows ... is logging you on with a temporary profile".  Which is it?  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...  Also, following up on @Ben's comment, try logging in as ".\username".

Comment: What antivirus are you running?

Comment: @skub : -- I am running NO antivirus (only 3 wk old install) and PersonalFirewall ....  The logging in as ".\username" is of no avail as what's happening is it LOGS IN OK ... _but does not create the permanent user profile files..._   Thanks for trying to help I'm still stuck with one user

Comment: Interesting question.  My first instinct is domain/group policy or permissions on the users folder.  I think you have pretty well ruled those out.  Have you done anything special with this installation?  It sounds like change the default location for users folders?  Has there ever been a virus issue?  Something is very odd here.

Answer (score -1):

1. Let that user whose account cannot be created in that machine log in to another computer which is able to create the account.
2. Log in to the same computer which is capable of creating accounts as admin, 
   go to `c:\users\` copy his profile to an external hard drive.
3. Log in as admin to the computer which is not able to create his user profile, and paste his profile under `c:\users\` once you have copied to that location, right click on that user's profile which you just copied, go to PROPERTIES, click on the SECURITY TAB, go to ADVANCED, CHANGE PERMISSION, ADD under add search his user name from the domain once you have it check name, click OK give that name full control from permission, and that's it. His account will be permanent and he will be able to log in with the permanent profile.